# repeat $() all over the place or declare once and reuse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, overhead

Using jQuery, if I am writing code like this

```
$('blah').doSomething(); 
//bunch of code
$('blah').doSomethingElse();
//bunch of code
$('blah').doOtherStuff();
```

Is a new jQuery object being created each time I say $('blah') ?

If so, would it reduce object creation overhead to do something like this instead:

```
var blah = $('blah');
blah.doSomething(); 
//bunch of code
blah.doSomethingElse();
//bunch of code
blah.doOtherStuff();
```

Make sense?

Comment: Here's the relevant section of jQuery Fundamentals: http://jqfundamentals.com/book/index.html#example-3.9

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely correct!

***Why Cache***

Another benefit of caching is code maintainability. If the selector is only in one place, changing it only needs to be done in one place. Trust me that makes life easier when maintaining code.

***Chain***

Although you can go one step further (where relevant), and chain your calls:

```
$('blah')
.doSomething()
.doSomethingElse()
.doOtherStuff();
```

This is slightly better for 2 reasons. Firstly, you're not using the extra variable, so you save a tiny amount of memory. Secondly, the language doesn't perform lookups for each identifier use, so it's quicker.

***So, why do people still [over]use `$()`***

One reason people use lots of `$()` is because they don't know any better.

Another reason is because element selection used to be slower. But as with most things in the browser, querying objects with selectors is fast being optimised (`document.querySelectorAll`), which means it's not such a big deal to cache or not to cache, so maybe with that in mind they allow themselves not to cache.

Finally, there are benchmarks hanging around ([one](http://jsperf.com/jquery-cache-test) [two](http://jsperf.com/cache-jquery-objects) from a quick google) that try to claim that it doesn't matter or is maybe even faster *not* to cache. The problem with most of these benchmarks and why I suggest you be very wary about drawing conclusions from them, is that the DOM in the example is not real-world; it's overly simplistic. Secondly, the selectors are simplistic as well. So of course querying will be lightning fast and caching won't make a big difference, but I don't find them at all conclusive.

That said, if your example is similar to those of the benchmarks, then maybe you can draw your own circumstantial conclusions, and caching might just be a nuisance.

Comment: +1 for chaining. Also, IIRC from reading the source, jQuery will cache the last query, so in James' example, it wouldn't matter much.

Comment: but if the calls are in different places in the code then the above, "declare 1st, then reuse" would be a good practice?  If so, why do I see so much rampant $() being repeated all over the place?

Comment: I need to refine my question to reflect what I am trying to get at better. Is that kosher practice here?

Comment: @James, yes, you can update your question. Although I have tried to update my answer to explain why people might overuse `$()`.

Comment: @James - repetition of $() is rampant because a lot of people don't know any better; this is the same as how some non-jQuery people unnecessarily repeat `document.getElementById()` (or other DOM functions). Having said that, I would not bother trying to cache for use in multiple unrelated functions, but within a single function I _would_ cache because then it is simple to keep track of the caching variable - assuming I couldn't just chain as already suggested.